# Running For Loop via a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I am trying to recursively run through all sub-folders in 'C:\Temp' to get a list of file sizes, file names, file extensions and write it to a text file. I separate my values with a colon (:).

The below command works perfectly when I type it directly into the cmd prompt.
When I paste it into a .bat file and run it, I get the following message:

> The following usage of the path operator in batch-parameter substitution is invalid: %~fA : %~xA >> MyOutput.txt

If I substitue '%~zA' with '%%~zA', it still doesn't work.
This is my command:

```
for /R "C:\Temp" %A in (*.*) do echo %~zA : %~fA : %~xA >> MyOutput.txt
```

I'm very new to dos. Please could someone assist.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: It works here. Always %%A in a batch file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should double all percentages:

```
for /R "C:\Temp" %%A in (*.*) do echo %%~zA : %%~fA : %%~xA >> MyOutput.txt
```